# Python script suddenly not working on PowerBI Service

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm working with report on power bi service, and inside those report I am using some python code to visualize my data.

now, until yesterday (12 Feb 2020) My report work without problem, but then today when I try to open my reports an error occured on my python object.

[image: powerBI Service]

when I see the details of these errors, it only showed my this information

[image: error]

is there any updates on power BI service environment recently which could have cause this?

and is there any way for me to trace the error of python script on power bi service?

if there are anyone who had these kind of problems, I would very appreciate if you could share the fix to me.

this is my python code which I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(60,10), linewidth=800)
fig.patch.set_visible(False) 

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=0.99, bottom=0.1, top=0.99)

ax = plt.subplot()
linecolor = "darkgrey"
graphcolor = "#7F7F7F"

ax.grid(which="both",axis="x",color=linecolor,linewidth = 1.5)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)

ax = plt.gca() # get current axis
ax.spines["right"].set_color("none")  
ax.spines["left"].set_color("none")   
ax.spines["top"].set_color("none")    
ax.spines["bottom"].set_color("none") 

ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', colors =graphcolor)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=60,labelleft=False)

ax.step(dataset["Time"], dataset["current_ch"], where="post", color=graphcolor)
plt.show()
```

bests,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still don't know why my Python script suddenly not working.

but as a work around, I remove my python script and change it with the graphs which I could get on marketplace.
hope Microsoft would check this problem though..